# не отображаются svg картинки

Tags: html, css

Что делать если не отображаются svg картинки, которые экспортировал из фотошопа

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="111" height="24" viewBox="0 0 111 24">
      <path d="M13.93 8.17c5-1.67 5.34-7.88.45-7.88a5.06 5.06 0 0 0-4.06 2.88l-6.6 11.42A9.54 9.54 0 0 1 2.77 16 5.24 5.24 0 0 1 4 8.62L3 7.37c-5.14 3.28-3.63 12.75 5 12.75 7.26 0 10.66-8.81 5.93-11.95zM7.87 18.23a7.06 7.06 0 0 1-3.54-.85 12.72 12.72 0 0 0 1.23-1.75l4.13-7.15.66.07c5.76 1.21 3.47 9.68-2.48 9.68zM10.51 7l2-3.4c1.79-3.09 4.08-1.27 2.85 1C14.41 6.45 13 7 10.51 7z" fill="#fff"/>
      <path d="M110.08 13.37l-.17.19a11.55 11.55 0 0 1-4.49 3.44c.4-.64.71-1.32 1-1.84l2.71-4.65c2.29-3.89-1.42-5.19-3.92-2.95l.5-.85h-2.46l-3.84 6.66-.17.19a5.29 5.29 0 0 1-3.71 1.82l2.32-4c1.49-2.57.12-5-2.2-5-1.89 0-3.35.76-4.77 3.21l-1.2 2.1-1 1.72-.13.15c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l3.54-6.21c1.06-1.87 0-3.21-1.32-3.21a5 5 0 0 0-3.42 1.87l3.92-6.82H84L77.13 13.4l-.14.16A15.28 15.28 0 0 1 74 16.22c.78-2.34.62-5.92 2.13-9.07l-1.85-1c-1 1.39-3.23 4.6-5.45 7.2l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l2.46-4.3a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-.35-3.33l-1.34-1.63a1 1 0 0 1 .14-1.42l-1.27-1.39C62 5.06 61.92 6.45 62.8 7.59l.21.28c-1.09 1.53-2.55 3.61-4.15 5.5l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-4 3.68-5.76 3.68-1.51 0-2.41-.94-1.28-2.93l.24-.42c1.58.66 4.56.35 6.4-2.83l.35-.61c1.32-2.27 0-4-2-4a5.19 5.19 0 0 0-4.6 2.83l-2.34 4.11-.15.17a5.24 5.24 0 0 1-3.71 1.82l2.31-4a6 6 0 0 0 .92-2.81 2.1 2.1 0 0 0-2.22-2.2 2.86 2.86 0 0 0-1.6.54l3.12-5.41h-2.5L39 13.41l-.13.15c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l2.45-4.3a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-.35-3.33l-1.38-1.65a1 1 0 0 1 .14-1.42L33.6 3.81c-1.39 1.25-1.51 2.64-.6 3.78l.21.28c-1.09 1.53-2.55 3.61-4.15 5.5l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34L28 9h-1.43A2.55 2.55 0 0 0 24 6.48a5.45 5.45 0 0 0-4.2 2.83l-3.44 5.95c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49a6 6 0 0 0 3.4-1.6 1.9 1.9 0 0 0 2.13 1.6c2 0 4.36-2.17 6.4-4.53C31.13 12.85 32 11.62 34 9l.32.4a1.21 1.21 0 0 1 .14 1.39l-2.6 4.51c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49 1.43 0 3-1.07 4.51-2.52a2.58 2.58 0 0 0 2.83 2.62 5.43 5.43 0 0 0 4.18-2.29 4.16 4.16 0 0 0 .54 0 7.2 7.2 0 0 0 3.26-1c-.13 1.77 1.16 3.12 3.33 3.12 2.79 0 5.55-2.17 7.58-4.53 1.18-1.37 2.1-2.6 4.06-5.26l.33.4a1.21 1.21 0 0 1 .14 1.39l-2.6 4.51c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49s4.36-2.17 6.4-4.53c1.39-1.6 2.62-3.33 3.49-4.48-1 2.55-.45 7.13-2.78 7.13a1.37 1.37 0 0 1-1.16-.9l-1.53.8a2.67 2.67 0 0 0 2.68 2 6.65 6.65 0 0 0 .68 0h.07A8.61 8.61 0 0 0 75 17.06l-.84 1.47h2.48L80.38 12c3.78-4.74 5.46-4.13 4.39-2.31l-3.19 5.55c-1 1.81-.3 3.49 1.68 3.49 1.43 0 3-1.07 4.52-2.53 0 3.13 4.34 3.74 7 .38h.54A6.77 6.77 0 0 0 98 16l-4.47 7.75H96l7.34-12.77c2.74-3.73 4.46-2.36 3.82-1.25l-3.71 6.42a1 1 0 0 1-1.77 0l-1.39.66a2.67 2.67 0 0 0 2.69 2h.14c3.56-.07 5.9-2.2 7.91-4.53a1.54 1.54 0 0 0-.95-.91zm-55.9-3.45c1.42-2.43 3.92-2 2.45.52l-.35.61c-1.18 2-2.76 2-3.68 1.63zm-31.46 3.87c-1.49 2.34-3 3.45-4 3.45-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l3.42-6c1.32-2.29 3.94-1.7 2.74.52zm18.48 3.35a.92.92 0 0 1-1-.94 2.76 2.76 0 0 1 .43-1.27l.87-1.51A3.61 3.61 0 0 0 43.06 16a2.3 2.3 0 0 1-1.86 1.14zm2.57-2.38a2.65 2.65 0 0 1-1-2.22c0-1.75 1.7-4.6 3.09-4.6A.94.94 0 0 1 46.75 9a3 3 0 0 1-.47 1.46zm50.42-1.23h-.12A1.45 1.45 0 0 0 92.63 15a1.62 1.62 0 0 0 .24.83c-1.16 2-4 1.6-2.5-.94l1.87-3.23 1.18-2c1.72-2.93 4.08-1.77 2.6.78z" fill="#fff"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Грустить :) А если серьёзно, то приведите свой код: что за картинка, как и куда Вы её добавляете, где именно не отображается и т.д.

Comment: <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Логотип" width="111" height="24">

Comment: Вот код svg картинки:

Comment: отображается вроде https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzweKLJ

Comment: там просто fill="#fff" по этому не видно было надол сменить было на #000 если надо что бы было видно на белом

Answer (score 0):

Как и говорил кто-то в комментариях, у всех `path` стоит `fill="#fff"` Поэтому, svg на фине страницы не видно.
Вот что вышло в итоге:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="111" height="24" viewBox="0 0 111 24">
      <path d="M13.93 8.17c5-1.67 5.34-7.88.45-7.88a5.06 5.06 0 0 0-4.06 2.88l-6.6 11.42A9.54 9.54 0 0 1 2.77 16 5.24 5.24 0 0 1 4 8.62L3 7.37c-5.14 3.28-3.63 12.75 5 12.75 7.26 0 10.66-8.81 5.93-11.95zM7.87 18.23a7.06 7.06 0 0 1-3.54-.85 12.72 12.72 0 0 0 1.23-1.75l4.13-7.15.66.07c5.76 1.21 3.47 9.68-2.48 9.68zM10.51 7l2-3.4c1.79-3.09 4.08-1.27 2.85 1C14.41 6.45 13 7 10.51 7z" fill="#000"/>
      <path d="M110.08 13.37l-.17.19a11.55 11.55 0 0 1-4.49 3.44c.4-.64.71-1.32 1-1.84l2.71-4.65c2.29-3.89-1.42-5.19-3.92-2.95l.5-.85h-2.46l-3.84 6.66-.17.19a5.29 5.29 0 0 1-3.71 1.82l2.32-4c1.49-2.57.12-5-2.2-5-1.89 0-3.35.76-4.77 3.21l-1.2 2.1-1 1.72-.13.15c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l3.54-6.21c1.06-1.87 0-3.21-1.32-3.21a5 5 0 0 0-3.42 1.87l3.92-6.82H84L77.13 13.4l-.14.16A15.28 15.28 0 0 1 74 16.22c.78-2.34.62-5.92 2.13-9.07l-1.85-1c-1 1.39-3.23 4.6-5.45 7.2l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l2.46-4.3a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-.35-3.33l-1.34-1.63a1 1 0 0 1 .14-1.42l-1.27-1.39C62 5.06 61.92 6.45 62.8 7.59l.21.28c-1.09 1.53-2.55 3.61-4.15 5.5l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-4 3.68-5.76 3.68-1.51 0-2.41-.94-1.28-2.93l.24-.42c1.58.66 4.56.35 6.4-2.83l.35-.61c1.32-2.27 0-4-2-4a5.19 5.19 0 0 0-4.6 2.83l-2.34 4.11-.15.17a5.24 5.24 0 0 1-3.71 1.82l2.31-4a6 6 0 0 0 .92-2.81 2.1 2.1 0 0 0-2.22-2.2 2.86 2.86 0 0 0-1.6.54l3.12-5.41h-2.5L39 13.41l-.13.15c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l2.45-4.3a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-.35-3.33l-1.38-1.65a1 1 0 0 1 .14-1.42L33.6 3.81c-1.39 1.25-1.51 2.64-.6 3.78l.21.28c-1.09 1.53-2.55 3.61-4.15 5.5l-.17.19c-1.77 2.05-3.49 3.68-4.58 3.68-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34L28 9h-1.43A2.55 2.55 0 0 0 24 6.48a5.45 5.45 0 0 0-4.2 2.83l-3.44 5.95c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49a6 6 0 0 0 3.4-1.6 1.9 1.9 0 0 0 2.13 1.6c2 0 4.36-2.17 6.4-4.53C31.13 12.85 32 11.62 34 9l.32.4a1.21 1.21 0 0 1 .14 1.39l-2.6 4.51c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49 1.43 0 3-1.07 4.51-2.52a2.58 2.58 0 0 0 2.83 2.62 5.43 5.43 0 0 0 4.18-2.29 4.16 4.16 0 0 0 .54 0 7.2 7.2 0 0 0 3.26-1c-.13 1.77 1.16 3.12 3.33 3.12 2.79 0 5.55-2.17 7.58-4.53 1.18-1.37 2.1-2.6 4.06-5.26l.33.4a1.21 1.21 0 0 1 .14 1.39l-2.6 4.51c-1 1.82-.31 3.49 1.68 3.49s4.36-2.17 6.4-4.53c1.39-1.6 2.62-3.33 3.49-4.48-1 2.55-.45 7.13-2.78 7.13a1.37 1.37 0 0 1-1.16-.9l-1.53.8a2.67 2.67 0 0 0 2.68 2 6.65 6.65 0 0 0 .68 0h.07A8.61 8.61 0 0 0 75 17.06l-.84 1.47h2.48L80.38 12c3.78-4.74 5.46-4.13 4.39-2.31l-3.19 5.55c-1 1.81-.3 3.49 1.68 3.49 1.43 0 3-1.07 4.52-2.53 0 3.13 4.34 3.74 7 .38h.54A6.77 6.77 0 0 0 98 16l-4.47 7.75H96l7.34-12.77c2.74-3.73 4.46-2.36 3.82-1.25l-3.71 6.42a1 1 0 0 1-1.77 0l-1.39.66a2.67 2.67 0 0 0 2.69 2h.14c3.56-.07 5.9-2.2 7.91-4.53a1.54 1.54 0 0 0-.95-.91zm-55.9-3.45c1.42-2.43 3.92-2 2.45.52l-.35.61c-1.18 2-2.76 2-3.68 1.63zm-31.46 3.87c-1.49 2.34-3 3.45-4 3.45-.54 0-.85-.38-.28-1.34l3.42-6c1.32-2.29 3.94-1.7 2.74.52zm18.48 3.35a.92.92 0 0 1-1-.94 2.76 2.76 0 0 1 .43-1.27l.87-1.51A3.61 3.61 0 0 0 43.06 16a2.3 2.3 0 0 1-1.86 1.14zm2.57-2.38a2.65 2.65 0 0 1-1-2.22c0-1.75 1.7-4.6 3.09-4.6A.94.94 0 0 1 46.75 9a3 3 0 0 1-.47 1.46zm50.42-1.23h-.12A1.45 1.45 0 0 0 92.63 15a1.62 1.62 0 0 0 .24.83c-1.16 2-4 1.6-2.5-.94l1.87-3.23 1.18-2c1.72-2.93 4.08-1.77 2.6.78z" fill="#000"/>
    </svg>
```